# psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block, dont know how to fix it

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into my database using psycopg2 and I get this weird error. I tried some things but nothing works. This is my code:

```
def insert_transaction():
global username
now = datetime.now()
date_checkout = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
time_checkout = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

username = "Peter1"

connection_string = "host='localhost' dbname='Los Pollos Hermanos' user='postgres' password='******'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    query_check_1 = """(SELECT employeeid FROM employee WHERE username = %s);"""
    cursor.execute(query_check_1, (username,))
    employeeid = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    conn.commit()
except:
    print("Employee error")

try:
    query_check_2 = """SELECT MAX(transactionnumber) FROM Transaction"""
    cursor.execute(query_check_2)
    transactionnumber = cursor.fetchone()[0] + 1
    conn.commit()
except:
    transactionnumber = 1

""""---------INSERT INTO TRANSACTION------------"""


query_insert_transaction = """INSERT INTO transactie (transactionnumber, date, time, employeeemployeeid)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"""
data = (transactionnumber, date_checkout, time_checkout, employeeid)
cursor.execute(query_insert_transaction, data)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

this is the error:

```
", line 140, in insert_transaction
cursor.execute(query_insert_transaction, data) psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message means that one of the preceding SQL statements has resulted in an error.  If an exception occurs while executing an SQL statement you need to call the connection's rollback method (`conn.rollback()`) to reset the transaction's state. PostgreSQL will not permit further statement execution otherwise.

Ideally you want to record the actual error for later analysis, so your code ought to be structured like this:

```py
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error {e}')
    print('Anything else that you feel is useful')
    conn.rollback()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! I tried that already but it wont work. The printed error gives the samen transaction error. This is how i did it, maybe i made a small mistake that I did not see?

Comment: try:
        query_insert_transaction = """INSERT INTO Transactie (transactionnumber, date, time, employeeemployeeid)
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"""
        data = (transactionnumber, date_checkout, time_checkout, employeeid)
        cursor.execute(query_insert_transaction, data)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        conn.rollback()

Comment: "one of the _preceding_ SQL statements has failed" - you need to check what is happening in the earlier executions.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the `conn.rollback()` function after checking for errors and executing the code again should help!